# SQL Query to Get Periodic Summary Report

Tags: postgresql

Consider the Following Table

```
ID  |  Name |  Date | Amount 
----------
1   |  XYZ|  01 Jan 17 | 40

2   |  ABC |  12 Feb 17 | 130

3   |  DEF| 15 Jan 17 | 70

4   |  XYZ| 14 March 17 | 50
```

etc

---

I need to get the results like, total amount of less than 10 days of < query parameter && 10 to 30 days from query parameter and more than 30 days of query parameter along with name details, like periodic output how we can get this report.

How I can get this.
Please provide some information to get this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking -- in particular when you say "10 days."  10 days of what?  In the example below, I take that to mean time from today, but if you can clarify, perhaps we can refine the example.

```
select
  sum (case when current_date - date < 10 then amount else 0 end) as "< 10",
  sum (case when current_date - date between 10 and 30 then amount else 0 end) as "10-30",
  sum (case when current_date - date > 30 then amount else 0 end) as "> 30"
from
  mytable
```

If you didn't mean from today, that's easy enough to parameterize.